# Localisation for certain languages

Tags: localization

I was setting up localisation and was a bit confused finding certain langugae locales.
Urdu is spoken in Pakistan also known as Bihari but in Craft or Yii i18n data there is only en_pk. Is this a holder for incoming translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft only ships with a subset of Yii’s supported locales, to cut down on the filesize. It’s easy to add additional ones though. Instructions are here: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/adding-additional-locales